# Combinatorial Mathematics Question, perfect stability of a polynomial

Tags: numerical-methods

Consider a polynomial, $$P_n(x) = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1x + \ldots + \alpha_nx^{n}$$ to be perfectly conditioned or stable relative to perturbations in the data $x$ we must have, $$k_{rel} = \max\left(1,|\frac{P'_n(x)}{P_n(x)}|\right) = 1$$
Is there a way of constructing a condition to which this would be true for the polynomial $P_n(x)$? Assume that $x\in\mathbb{R}$ or just the finite floating point numbers that can be represented on a computer.

I think we need to state an assumption about the coefficients to make this be true, if anyone has any suggestions I would greatly appreciate it.

Here is my attempt:

Consider a polynomial, $$P_n(x) = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1x + \ldots + \alpha_nx^{n}$$ to be perfectly conditioned or stable relative to perturbations in the data $x$ we must have, $$k_{rel} = \max\left(1,|\frac{P'_n(x)}{P_n(x)}|\right) = 1$$ essentially we want $$|\sum_{i=0}^{n}\alpha_i x^{i}| \geq |\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(1+i)\alpha_{i+1}x^{i+1}|$$ if $p_n(x),p'_n(x) \geq 0$, $x\geq 0$ then we have $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\alpha_i x^{i} \geq \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(1+i)\alpha_{i+1}x^{i+1} \Leftrightarrow \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left[\alpha_i - (i + 1)\alpha_i\right]x^{i} + \alpha_n x^{n} \geq 0$$ $$\Leftrightarrow \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}-i\alpha_i x^{i} + \alpha_n x^{n} \geq 0 \rightarrow \alpha_n x^{n} \geq \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}i\alpha_i x^{i} \ \ \text{if} \ \ x\geq 0$$ thus we have our desired result. To provide an example let $p(x) = x$ for $x\geq 1$ then $p'(x) = 1$ and we have $k_{rel} = 1$ and thus we are perfectly conditioned.

Comment: If you want the condition to be true for all $x$, no way, because $P_n(x)/P_n'(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: sorry there was an error please see the edited version @David

Comment: Is the maximum taken over all real numbers or all complex numbers or over a smaller set?

Comment: @HansEngler good question, see edited version of question

Comment: It needs to have no real zeros.

Comment: For any $\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n$ with $n$ even it should be possible to find an $\alpha_0$ to satsify the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of an explicit relation for the coefficients. You can however get a crude estimate using the roots. Let $z_i$ be the distinct zeros of $P(x)$, with multiplicity $r_i$. Then

$$\frac{P'(x)}{P(x)}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{r_i}{(x-z_i)}.$$

It's clear that $z_i$ are all necessarily complex for there to be a chance of stability. A crude bound upper bound on the absolute value is:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{r_i}{|Im(z_i)|},$$

so demanding this is less than 1 will be sufficient. You could maybe try playing around with Vieta's relations by getting a common denominator, to try and get something in terms of the $\alpha_i$.